# Exception block in PLSQL exiting the block

Tags: oracle, api, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am using the following code  block to update my front end segment.
But when i am compiling this

```
DECLARE
   p_person_id                   NUMBER          := NULL;
   p_business_group_id           NUMBER;
   p_id_flex_num                 NUMBER;
------------------
   p_analysis_criteria_id        NUMBER          := NULL;
   p_person_analysis_id          NUMBER          := NULL;
   p_per_object_version_number   NUMBER          := NULL;
   v_err                         VARCHAR2 (1000) := NULL;
   p_medical_id                  VARCHAR2 (100)  := NULL;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT *
               FROM xx_hr_upload_master_data_new
              WHERE person_id IS NOT NULL
                AND business_group_id IS NOT NULL
                AND medical_id IS NOT NULL)
   LOOP
      p_id_flex_num := 50530;
      BEGIN
         SELECT   sv.segment1, NVL (sit.object_version_number, 1),
                  sit.analysis_criteria_id, MAX (sit.person_analysis_id)
             INTO p_medical_id, p_per_object_version_number,
                  p_analysis_criteria_id, p_person_analysis_id
             FROM fnd_id_flex_structures_tl sttl,
                  fnd_id_flex_structures st,
                  per_person_analyses sit,
                  per_analysis_criteria sv
            WHERE sttl.id_flex_structure_name = 'ISPs Medical Data'
              AND sttl.LANGUAGE = USERENV ('LANG')
              AND st.id_flex_code = sttl.id_flex_code
              AND st.id_flex_num = sttl.id_flex_num
              AND st.id_flex_num = sit.id_flex_num
              AND st.id_flex_num = sv.id_flex_num
              AND sit.analysis_criteria_id = sv.analysis_criteria_id
              AND sit.person_id = i.person_id
         --and sv.SEGMENT1 = '4602001140'
         GROUP BY sv.segment1,
                  NVL (sit.object_version_number, 1),
                  sit.analysis_criteria_id;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            p_medical_id := NULL;
            p_per_object_version_number := 1;
            p_person_analysis_id := NULL;
            p_analysis_criteria_id := NULL;
            p_person_analysis_id := NULL;
            p_per_object_version_number := NULL;
            p_person_id := NULL;
      END;
      BEGIN
------------------------------------------------
         IF (p_medical_id IS NULL AND p_analysis_criteria_id IS NULL)
         THEN
            -- create a new record in the SIT (Special Information Type)table .
            p_person_id := i.person_id;
            p_medical_id := TO_CHAR (i.medical_id);
-----------------------------
            hr_sit_api.create_sit
                  (p_validate                       => FALSE,
                   p_person_id                      => p_person_id,
                   p_business_group_id              => i.business_group_id,
                   p_id_flex_num                    => p_id_flex_num,
                   p_effective_date                 => TRUNC (SYSDATE),
                   p_date_from                      => TRUNC (SYSDATE),
                   p_segment1                       => p_medical_id,
                   p_analysis_criteria_id           => p_analysis_criteria_id,
                   p_person_analysis_id             => p_person_analysis_id,
                   p_pea_object_version_number      => p_per_object_version_number
                  );
         ELSE
            -- employee has previous Billing_Acc_Num then update that number in  the SIT table .
            hr_sit_api.update_sit
                 (p_validate                       => FALSE,
                  p_person_analysis_id             => p_person_analysis_id,
                  p_pea_object_version_number      => p_per_object_version_number,
                  p_date_from                      => TRUNC (SYSDATE),
                  p_segment1                       => p_medical_id,
                  p_analysis_criteria_id           => p_analysis_criteria_id
                 );
         END IF;
         UPDATE xx_hr_upload_master_data_new xx
            SET xx.error_msg = 'Done',
                xx.emp_data = 'Done'
          WHERE xx.business_group_id = i.business_group_id
            AND xx.employee_number = i.employee_number;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            p_analysis_criteria_id := NULL;
            p_person_analysis_id := NULL;
            p_per_object_version_number := NULL;
            p_person_id := NULL;
            p_medical_id := NULL;
            v_err := NULL;
            v_err := SQLERRM;
            UPDATE xx_hr_upload_master_data_new xx
               SET xx.error_msg = v_err
             WHERE xx.business_group_id = i.business_group_id
               AND xx.employee_number = i.employee_number;
      END;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Now when the select query is not fetching anything, the exception block is entered where all the variables are initiated to null.

I want that after this the begin where the create api is called inside the condition IF (p_medical_id IS NULL AND p_analysis_criteria_id IS NULL)
should be entered. But this is not happening and the program exits after this exception block after entering the exception block.

Comment: I can't see any reason that this program should behave as you report. I suggest adding some DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE calls at various points to figure out what the code flow actually is. You might also change the first exception handler to `WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND` instead of `WHEN OTHERS`, if in fact you're trying to trap the condition where the SELECT doesn't find anything.

Comment: i have added DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in the exception block. still its going into error

Comment: @LalitKumarB - a comment such as yours with no explanation given is not helpful. Please consider expanding on this. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis, I assumed the `exception when other then null` is a very common and famous bad coding practice. Perhaps, you are right I should have added some explanation. I tried to summarize it here https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/  I wish Oracle wouldn't allow it at all, however, post 11g we do have a warning, alas! few developers don't even care. I would suggest to the developers, at least don't have any exception blocks wgile testing phase. Let all the errors raise during testing phase.

Comment: Using a debugger will help you to track down the problem. Are you using an IDE? Your post is tagged with 'PLSQL Developer'. If this means the IDE by the same name, then use the built in debugger.

Comment: i have added the dbms_output.put_line in the xception block. still its running into error and the program is stopping without updating any column @LalitKumarB

Answer (score 0):

A hint might be:
The first select will not raise any exception if it gets no result. If it gets no result then the for-loop just won't be entered, so the only thing that will happen is the commit.
(The select inside the for-loop will raise an exception if it gets 0 rows or more than 1 row. The reason is 'select ... into ...': When using 'into' the select must return exact 1 row.)